# Regex to handle leading spaces (notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a line in a file opened in notepad++

```
  0 <? 0.00 - (multi) Salt
```

Note: There are 2 leading spaces at the start of the line.

Using regex replacement in *only one* go, I have to change the above line to :

```
0,0.00,multi,Salt
```

I have tried is : replace

```
  ( \d*) <\? \d.\d\d - \(multi\) *
```

with

```
\1,\2,multi,
```

It works fine. Only problem is it adds a leading space at every line in notepad++

How can I modify my regex to not add leading space at the start of every line?

Note L I cannot use the option of "Trim Leading space in notepad".

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Note: My file has more lines like

```
  0 <? 0.00 - (multi) Salt  
  1 <? 0.00 - (multi) Vinegar   
  2 <? 0.00 - (multi) Salt and Vinegar  
  3 <? 0.00 - (multi) BBQ Sauce 
  4 <? 0.00 - (multi) Chilli Sauce  
  5 <? 0.00 - (multi) Hawaiian Sauce    
  6 <? 0.00 - (multi) Brown Sauce   
  7 <? 0.00 - (multi) Garlic Mayo and Herb Sauce    
  8 <? 0.00 - (multi) Mayo  
  9 <? 0.00 - (multi) Salad 
  10 <? 0.00 - (multi) Lettuce  
  11 <? 0.00 - (multi) Cabbage
```

[image: Tried suggestions below]

Comment: Just move the space out of the capturing group - `"  (\d*) <\? \d.\d\d - \(multi\) *"`. See [`^ {2}(\d*) *<\? *(\d\.\d{2}) *- *\(multi\) *`](https://regex101.com/r/xA5cV6/1).

Comment: I tried that. It still adds a space at the start of the line.

Comment: See my demo. I think it should work.

Comment: Your demo just looks great. Not sure why it does not match any line in my notepad++ editor, leave alone replacement

Comment: Did you check regex box? Are the spaces regular or hard spaces (&#0160;)?

Comment: Yeah I did. Those are regular spaces.

Comment: Try `^\h{2}(\d*)\h*<\?\h*(\d\.\d{2})\h*-\h*\(multi\)\h*`. Well, I have this line:   `0 <? 0.00 - (multi) Salt`  (with 2 spaces at the start) and it works.

Comment: So, to give more info My file has more lines where numbers can be 2 digits too. Like  0 <? 0.00 - (multi) Salt 
   1 <? 0.00 - (multi) Vinegar 
   10 <? 0.00 - (multi) Lettuce 
   11 <? 0.00 - (multi) Cabbage 
   12 <? 0.00 - (multi) Onion 
   13 <? 0.00 - (multi) Tomato 
   14 <? 0.20 - (multi) Sauce Separate 
   15 <? 0.20 - (multi) Salad Separate 
   16 <? 0.40 - (multi) Sauce and Salad Separate 
   17 <? 0.00 - (multi) No 
   18 <? 0.00 - (multi) Less

Comment: Please add to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I just did that. Edited the question.

Comment: In your image, you have *Extended* checked, not *Regular expression*.

Comment: I provided the comment to move out the space from the capturing group and suggested checking the regex option, but you accepted the answer that was a copy of my comment. Well, no offense, but I'd act differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To use a regex-based replacement in Notepad++, turn on the *Regular expression* radio button at the bottom of the Find and Replace window!** (see my settings below)

Here is a regex that must work for you:

```
^\h{2}(\d*)\h*<\?\h*(\d\.\d{2})\h*-\h*\(multi\)\h*
```

Replace with `\1,\2,multi,`

The `\h` is a *horizontal whitespace* (to exclude newlines). Two occurrences can be matched with `{2}` limiting quantifier (no need repeating the subpattern).

See the settings:

[image]

**NOTE**: If you have more than 1 leading spaces, change `\h{2}` to `\h{2,}`:

```
^\h{2,}(\d*)\h*<\?\h*(\d\.\d{2})\h*-\h*\(multi\)\h*
```

Comment: Isn't there a leading space in your lines?

Comment: Nowhere to be seen. Where do you see it in the screenshot? There are trailing spaces only. Do you need to remove trailing whitespace? Use `\h+$` to replace with empty string.

Comment: How do I paste my screenshot here? I need to share it to show where I am going wrong. I am doing the same thing. It does not work.

Comment: Just edit your question I guess. There is an image insertion button. Maybe you have more than 2 spaces in the line start? Replace `{2}` with `{2,}`.

Comment: I have added the image in the question. Please check.

Comment: @stribizhev Would this not just be simpler and allow for more dynamic content? `^\h+(\d+)\h*<\?\h*([\d.]+)\W+(\w+)\W+([\w\h]+?)\h*$` See it [here](http://bit.ly/1lefCi5).

Comment: @stribizhev This worked like a charm!   ^\h{2,}(\d*)\h*<\?\h*(\d\.\d{2})\h*-\h*\(multi\)\h*  Thank you so much! I owe you big time.

Comment: Please consider accepting then. You accepted a solution that does not work.

Comment: Also, you easily check how many spaces you have if you go to View menu and check *Show Symbol -> Show All Characters*.

Comment: My bad.. I accepted the wrong answer. I have tried undoing it and accepted your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
"  ( \d*) <\? \d.\d\d - \(multi\) *"
```

Your regular expression has a space inside the first group: `( \d*)`. Remove it and you will be fine: `(\d*)`. However, (unrelated) you're not capturing your second group nor `Salt` yet.

Comment: I just tried that now.  (\d*) <\? \d.\d\d - \(multi\) *                                                               It still does not work. It adds a leading space in notepad++.

Comment: @user2805924 if the answer didn't work you shouldn't accept it. Always test answers before accepting.

Comment: @chris85 In this case, it was the other way around: the comment was made first, then apparently found to be false after all, and the answer got accepted. I do agree with your concern about consistency, though; one way to go about it would be to delete the initial comment.

Comment: Yup, that's a bad comment in that case. @user2805924 you should remove that comment so future visitors wont skip this over.

Answer (score 0):

`^\h+(\d+)\h*<\?\h*([\d.]+)\W+(\w+)\W+([\w\h]+?)\h*$` See it [here](http://bit.ly/1lefCi5).

Answer (score 0):

To capture all in four groups is working in my editor

Find what: `\s\s(\d+).+(\d[.]\d+).+\((\w+).*?(\w+\b)`
Replace with: `$1,$2,$3,$4`

See the attached photo shot below ..
[image]